# Is there a way to move multiple rigged characters simultaneously?

Tags: objects, armature, transforms, bones

Is it possible to select multiple root bones, in multiple armatures, and then translate them simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without some custom script (custom modal operator etc.).

The workaround is to child_of the root bones with constraints to Empty and move the empty. Then Pose > Apply > Visual Transform to Pose and delete the constraints.

There is an addon that lets you setup child_ofs easily or to keyframe them even: [Dynamic parent](http://www.pasteall.org/57869/python)